# Export Roots of EigenValue Function from Mathematica to Excel file

Tags: export, data

```
For[i=2,i<200, i++, Print[FindRoot[1-x Cot [x]==24,{x,i}]]
```

I have this equation in for loop. it prints the value but I want to export these values in excel file. Can anyone please help me. I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 1 - x Cot[x] == 24;

roots = x /. NSolve[{eqn, 0 < x < 200}, x];

Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eqn], {x, 0, 200},
 PlotRange -> {-10, 50},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[{#, 24} & /@ roots]}]
```

[image]

```
Export["roots.xls", roots]

(* "roots.xls" *)

roots == (Import["roots.xls"] // Flatten)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `Values` to extract the values of the roots.

```
output = Values @@@ 
  Table[FindRoot[1 - x Cot[x] == 24, {x, i}], {i, 2, 200}]
Export["data.xls", output]
Import["data.xls"]
```

You can also set `$Output`  to accept the `Print`.

```
$Output = "abc.txt";
For[i = 2, i < 200, i++, 
 Print[Values @@ FindRoot[1 - x Cot[x] == 24, {x, i}]]]
Export["newdata.txt", Import["abc.txt"]]
Import["newdata.txt"]
```